# How to use JavaScript EventTarget?

Tags: javascript, events

I would like to create a custom event emitter in my client-side programs. I am referencing this (sparse) documentation for [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)

**My implementation attempt**

```
var Emitter = function Emitter() {
  EventTarget.call(this);
};

Emitter.prototype = Object.create(EventTarget.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: Emitter
  }
});
```

**My desired usage**

```
var e = new Emitter();

e.addEventListener("hello", function() {
  console.log("hello there!");
});

e.dispatchEvent(new Event("hello"));
// "hello there!"
```

**Where it fails**

```
var e = new Emitter();
// TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**

The following is possible, but it's a hack that depends on a dummy DOMElement

```
var fake = document.createElement("phony");
fake.addEventListener("hello", function() { console.log("hello there!"); });
fake.dispatchEvent(new Event("hello"));
// "hello there!"
```

I'd like to know how to do this without having to use the dummy element

Comment: `Emitter.prototype = Object.create(Emitter.prototype, …)` - wait, what?

Comment: `EventTarget` is just an interface, not a constructor. Also, you cannot inherit from native DOM structures.

Comment: Bergi, the `Object.create` line sets up the prototype and the proper constructor. It was an attempt to inherit from the EventTarget "class".

Comment: I know what it does. Yet you didn't try to inherit from `EventTarget`, but from `Emitter` itself…

Comment: @Bergi, wups. That was just a typo in the code example here. Fixed.

Comment: 6 years later this is much much easier

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum care to share what you have in mind?

Comment: As @BenjaminGruenbaum says nowdays is easier, take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917410/1647238

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I gave up on this awhile ago, but recently needed it again. Here's what I ended up using.

> ES6

```js
class Emitter {
  constructor() {
    var delegate = document.createDocumentFragment();
    [
      'addEventListener',
      'dispatchEvent',
      'removeEventListener'
    ].forEach(f =>
      this[f] = (...xs) => delegate[f](...xs)
    )
  }
}

// sample class to use Emitter
class Example extends Emitter {}

// run it
var e = new Example()
e.addEventListener('something', event => console.log(event))
e.dispatchEvent(new Event('something'))
```

---

> ES5

```js
function Emitter() {
  var eventTarget = document.createDocumentFragment()

  function delegate(method) {
    this[method] = eventTarget[method].bind(eventTarget)
  }

  [
    "addEventListener",
    "dispatchEvent",
    "removeEventListener"
  ].forEach(delegate, this)
}

// sample class to use it
function Example() {
  Emitter.call(this)
}

// run it
var e = new Example()

e.addEventListener("something", function(event) {
  console.log(event)
})

e.dispatchEvent(new Event("something"))
```

Yeah!

---

For those that need to support older versions of ecmascript, here you go

```
// IE < 9 compatible
function Emitter() {
  var eventTarget = document.createDocumentFragment();

  function addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, wantsUntrusted) {
    return eventTarget.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, wantsUntrusted);
  }

  function dispatchEvent(event) {
    return eventTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  function removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture) {
    return eventTarget.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
  }

  this.addEventListener = addEventListener;
  this.dispatchEvent = dispatchEvent;
  this.removeEventListener = removeEventListener;
}
```

The usage stays the same

Comment: While you found a solution, it isn't the best way to solve problems like this one. You have a tight-coupling here and that could fail in some browsers.

Comment: @Scorpion, then please share the best way to solve this problem. I also see no "tight coupling" as Emitter can be used as a standalone or mixed into your other objects as desired. For SO, I'm not going to write a polyfill that works in every browser, but the nice part about `Emitter` is it gives you a good place to modify methods that need cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: If you use this solution keep in mind that keyword `this` inside the callback points to a `DocumentFragment` instead of your object, if you need to avoid such behavior use the `bind` method for the callback, as in `e.addEventListener("something", callback.bind(e));`

Comment: @IvanCastellanos Yeah, I suppose if you're relying on `this` it's worth heeding the warning.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos Couldn't that binding of the listener also be done in the redirection implementation of `addEventListener`?

Comment: wonder if we could make it work with typescript

Answer (score 10):

Bergi was right about the part, that `EventTarget` is just an interface and not a constructor.

There are multiple objects in js that are valid event targets. As mentioned [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget): 
*Element, document, and window are the most common event targets*, but there are also others for example `Websocket`. Anyway, all of them are given.

If you make a short test, you can notice few things:

```
EventTarget.isPrototypeOf(WebSocket); // true

var div = document.createElement("div");

EventTarget.isPrototypeOf(div.constructor); // true

typeof EventTarget // function

EventTarget() // TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

`EventTarget` is prototype of these constructors, which is something you can't set for any other constructor (and even if you could, it wouldnt probably work). Also it is a function, but not callable one.

**Now this is the time when you ask:** So what is it `EventTarget` good for and how can I use it?

We have 3 methods that each event emitter needs to implement and there was probably a need to bind these methods together, so we have an interface for them. Which means you can't use `EventTarget` for calling purposes, but some other native functions might. This is similar like creating elements, we have `document.createElement` factory method and we don't (can't) use `new HTMLDivElement()` to create a new element, but we can compare constructors of two elements.

**Conclusion**

If you want to create custom event emitter, you always have to create some dummy object or use some that already exists. From my point of view, it doesn't matter what object it will be.

Some methods are not callable, but still can be compared as properties of objects. Therefore they are visible. `EventTarget` is one of them.

Comment: Your sentence, "If you want to create custom event emitter, you always have to create some dummy object or use some that already exists.", solved a lot of problems for me.  Thank you for that suggestion!

Answer (score 8):

There are 3 ways to achieve this depending on browser support.

1) EventTarget is now constructable, so just extend it:

```
class MyEventTarget extends EventTarget {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}
```

2) The DOM 'Node' interface implements EventTarget, so just implement that instead:

```
function MyEventTarget(){
    var target = document.createTextNode(null);
    this.addEventListener = target.addEventListener.bind(target);
    this.removeEventListener = target.removeEventListener.bind(target);
    this.dispatchEvent = target.dispatchEvent.bind(target);
}
MyEventTarget.prototype = EventTarget.prototype;
```

3) Roll your own (assuming no options arg) & dispatch async:

```
function MyEventTarget(){
    this.__events = new Map();
}
MyEventTarget.prototype = {
    addEventListener(type, listener){
        var listeners = this.__events.get(type);
        if(!listeners){
            listeners = new Set();
            this.__events.set(type, listeners);
        }
        listeners.add(listener);
    },

    removeEventListener(type, listener){
        var listeners = this.__events.get(type);
        if(listeners){
            listeners.delete(listener);
            if(listeners.size === 0){
                this.__events.delete(type);
            }
        }
    },

    dispatchEvent(event){
        var listeners = this.__events.get(event.type);
        if(listeners){
            for(let listener of listeners){
                setTimeout(listener.call(null, event), 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace Map()/Set() with {}/[] if required.

All 3 of these options can be tested with:

```
var target = new MyEventTarget();
target.addEventListener('test', (e) => {console.log(e.detail);}, false);

var event = new CustomEvent('test', {detail : 'My Test Event'});
target.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Any object that needs to implement your own 'EventTarget' interface can inherit it exactly as the native one does:

```
function Person(name){
    MyEventTarget.call(this);
    this.__name = name;
}
Person.prototype = {
    __proto__ : MyEventTarget.prototype,

    get name(){ return this.__name;}
}
```

Comment: About "roll your own": `dispatchEvent()` must call listeners synchronously, set `this`, support `object.handleEvent`, and catch exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

`EventTarget` is now specified as constructible in the [DOM living standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-eventtarget). It is supported in [Chrome 64](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5721972856061952) (already out) and [Firefox 59](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1379688) (coming March 13).

Comment: quick check in v8 shows that `e = Object.create(new EventTarget()); e.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));` yields an "invocation error" so it is still not inheritable.

Comment: @Kyle can you please clarify what do you mean by non-inheritable - I see tons of EventTarget-based definitions in  idl files

Comment: @shabunc i simply mean that it's not possible to call `dispatchEvent` on a runtime object that inherits from `EventTarget` even though the method exists. all the builtin DOM elements and such do inherit from `EventTarget` successfully.

Answer (score 5):

Without taking into consideration browser support where `EventTarget` can not be instantiated as a constructor and only to enrich this issue with yet another functional example.

According to the compatibility list described by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) itself in this date (October 7, 2018):

**EventTarget** (constructor):

- **desktop**:

  - Chrome 64
  - Firefox 59
  - Opera 51
- **mobile**:

  - WebView 64
  - Chrome Android 64
  - Firefox Android 59
  - Opera Android 51

---

Extends:

```
class Emitter extends EventTarget {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

You could create common methods in many event plugins like: `on()`, `off()`, `.once()` and `emit()` (using `CustomEvent`):

```js
/**
 * Emmiter - Event Emitter
 * @license The MIT License (MIT)             - [https://github.com/subversivo58/Emitter/blob/master/LICENSE]
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2020 Lauro Moraes - [https://github.com/subversivo58]
 * @version 0.1.0 [development stage]         - [https://github.com/subversivo58/Emitter/blob/master/VERSIONING.md]
 */
const sticky = Symbol()
class Emitter extends EventTarget {
    constructor() {
        super()
        // store listeners (by callback)
        this.listeners = {
            '*': [] // pre alocate for all (wildcard)
        }
        // l = listener, c = callback, e = event
        this[sticky] = (l, c, e) => {
            // dispatch for same "callback" listed (k)
            l in this.listeners ? this.listeners[l].forEach(k => k === c ? k(e.detail) : null) : null
        }
    }
    on(e, cb, once = false) {
        // store one-by-one registered listeners
        !this.listeners[e] ? this.listeners[e] = [cb] : this.listeners[e].push(cb);
        // check `.once()` ... callback `CustomEvent`
        once ? this.addEventListener(e, this[sticky].bind(this, e, cb), { once: true }) : this.addEventListener(e, this[sticky].bind(this, e, cb))
    }
    off(e, Fn = false) {
        if ( this.listeners[e] ) {
            // remove listener (include ".once()")
            let removeListener = target => {
                this.removeEventListener(e, target)
            }
            // use `.filter()` to remove expecific event(s) associated to this callback
            const filter = () => {
                this.listeners[e] = this.listeners[e].filter(val => val === Fn ? removeListener(val) : val);
                // check number of listeners for this target ... remove target if empty
                this.listeners[e].length === 0 ? e !== '*' ? delete this.listeners[e] : null : null
            }
            // use `while()` to iterate all listeners for this target
            const iterate = () => {
                let len = this.listeners[e].length;
                while (len--) {
                    removeListener(this.listeners[e][len])
                }
                // remove all listeners references (callbacks) for this target (by target object)
                e !== '*' ? delete this.listeners[e] : this.listeners[e] = []
            }
            Fn && typeof Fn === 'function' ? filter() : iterate()
        }
    }
    emit(e, d) {
        this.listeners['*'].length > 0 ? this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('*', {detail: d})) : null;
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(e, {detail: d}))
    }
    once(e, cb) {
        this.on(e, cb, true)
    }
}

const MyEmitter = new Emitter()

// one or more listeners for same target ...
MyEmitter.on('xyz', data => {
    console.log('first listener: ', data)
})
MyEmitter.on('xyz', data => {
    console.log('second listener: ', data)
})

// fire event for this target
MyEmitter.emit('xyz', 'zzzzzzzzzz...') // see listeners show

// stop all listeners for this target
MyEmitter.off('xyz')

// try new "emit" listener event ?
MyEmitter.emit('xyz', 'bu bu bu') // nothing ;)

// fire a "once" ? Yes, fire
MyEmitter.once('abc', data => {
    console.log('fired by "once": ', data)
})

// run
MyEmitter.emit('abc', 'Hello World') // its show listener only once

// test "once" again
MyEmitter.emit('abc', 'Hello World') // nothing
```

Answer (score 5):

`EventTarget()` constructor is now [supported in most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_eventtarget_eventtarget).

For the browsers which still do not support it, there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/event-target) available.

This means that it's as simple as:

```
var e = new EventTarget();

e.addEventListener("hello", function() {
  console.log("hello there!");
});

e.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("hello"));
// "hello there!"
```

For the sake of completeness, in Node or an Electron app you would do

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');

var e = new EventEmitter();

e.addListener("hello", function() {
  console.log("hello there!");
});

e.emit("hello")
// "hello there!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it using [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent), cross-browser ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUJNz)):

```
// listen to event
window.addEventListener("say", function(e) { alert(e.detail.word); });

// create and dispatch the event
var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
event.initCustomEvent('say', true, true, 
    { "word": "Hello!" });

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You'd need to use `window` or `document` or any other existing DOM element to register listeneres and dispatch the event. `EventTarget` is not a object, it's an interface. Try accessing `EventTarget` in JavaScript console and you'll see that.

Comment: MDN documentation specifically says this usage is ["old-fashioned"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#The_old-fashioned_way) and it kind of sucks that I have to attach to the window (global object). Anyway, I've made an edit to show how you can improve this. Still, it would be nice to encapsulate the events.

Comment: @naomik, the edit you made doesn't work in IE9, IE10, IE11. I rolled it back.

Comment: I think it would've been more constructive to make a note for that solution then. Now we just have a solution using the old Java-influenced API that doesn't even fully solve my problem. And for what it's worth, [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) is only documented to support IE >= 9.0, so it's a safe assumption that I'm not looking for an answer that supports an earlier version of IE.

Comment: @naomik, it's not about `EventTarget`, it's about `new CustomEvent(...)` **not working in IE9-IE11**, a sad fact. So you have to stick with `document.createEvent("CustomEvent")`, unless you don't care about IE at all. That's why I rolled back your edit.

Comment: As to `EventTarget`, it doesn't exist in IE9-11 either, but that's expected. In the DOM standard, [it's defined as *interface*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget) on a DOM Node object, rather than a standalone object. Although Firefox and Chrome have chosen to implement it as an object, Microsoft may never follow this, as it is a non-standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try my simple ES6 implemetation.

```js
class DOMEventTarget {
  constructor() {
    this.listeners = new Map();
  }
  addEventListener(type, listener) {
    this.listeners.set(listener.bind(this), {
      type, listener
    });
  }
  removeEventListener(type, listener) {
    for(let [key, value] of this.listeners){
      if(value.type !== type || listener !== value.listener){
        continue;
      }
      this.listeners.delete(key);
    }
  }
  dispatchEvent(event) {
    Object.defineProperty(event, 'target',{value: this});
    this['on' + event.type] && this['on' + event.type](event);
    for (let [key, value] of this.listeners) {
      if (value.type !== event.type) {
        continue;
      }
      key(event);
    }
  }
}

let eventEmitter = new DOMEventTarget();
eventEmitter.addEventListener('test', e => {
  console.log('addEventListener works');
});
eventEmitter.ontest = e => console.log('ontype works');
eventEmitter.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'));
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to implement the EventTarget "Interface".

1) Like [mdn suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) use **javascript prototypes**. In my opinion this is **clearly not the best approach** to do this. The simple reason is that everybody who does use your library has to know that he needs to add a `listeners` property to his constructor function.

```
function implement_event_target_interface(target_constructor_function) 
{
    target_constructor_function.prototype.listeners = null;
    target_constructor_function.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, callback) {
        if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
            this.listeners[type] = [];
        }
        this.listeners[type].push(callback);
    };

    target_constructor_function.prototype.removeEventListener = function(type, callback) {
        if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
            return;
        }
        var stack = this.listeners[type];
        for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (stack[i] === callback){
            stack.splice(i, 1);
            return;
            }
        }
    };

    target_constructor_function.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(event) {
        if (!(event.type in this.listeners)) {
            return true;
        }
        var stack = this.listeners[event.type].slice();

        for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
            stack[i].call(this, event);
        }
        return !event.defaultPrevented;
    };
}

let Person = function()
{
    this.listeners = {}; // Every contructor that implements the event_target_interface must have this property. This is not very practical and intuitive for the library-user.

    this.send_event = function() {
        var event = new CustomEvent('test_event', { 'detail': "test_detail" });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}

implement_event_target_interface(Person);

let person = new Person();

person.addEventListener('test_event', function (e) { 
    console.log("catched test_event from person")
}.bind(this), false);

person.send_event();
```

And not only that, it gets even worse when you use constructor inheritance on `Person`, because you also need to inherit the prototype in order to be able to send events.

```
let Student = function() {
    Person.call(this);
}

Student.prototype = Person.prototype;
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

let student = new Student();

student.addEventListener('test_event', function (e) { 
    console.log("catched test_event from student")
}.bind(this), false);

student.send_event();
```

2) Use **constructor inheritance**. **Much much better**.

```
function EventTarget() 
{
    this.listeners = {};

    this.addEventListener = function(type, callback) {
        if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
            this.listeners[type] = [];
        }
        this.listeners[type].push(callback);
    };

    this.removeEventListener = function(type, callback) {
        if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
            return;
        }
        var stack = this.listeners[type];
        for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (stack[i] === callback){
            stack.splice(i, 1);
            return;
            }
        }
    };

    this.dispatchEvent = function(event) {
        if (!(event.type in this.listeners)) {
            return true;
        }
        var stack = this.listeners[event.type].slice();

        for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
            stack[i].call(this, event);
        }
        return !event.defaultPrevented;
    };
}

let Person = function()
{
    EventTarget.call(this);

    this.send_event = function() {
        var event = new CustomEvent('test_event', { 'detail': "test_detail" });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}

let person = new Person();

person.addEventListener('test_event', function (e) { 
    console.log("catched test_event from person")
}.bind(this), false);

person.send_event();
```

Comment: Invader this is fundamentally incorrect, please see my answer

Comment: Can you please explain what is incorrect? I did not say that these are the only two ways. Yes you can also use the new EventTarget constructor. Defenitely not worth a downvote, since my answer at least points out pros and cons instead of just giving three examples and not pointing out anything about why and when to use or not use an approach x.

Comment: 1) The EventTarget is a constructor and has been for a while so is both directly construtcable and inheritable. 2) Your comment about the difficulties of inheriting an implementation (which I hope I addressed) and 3) the main reason - your assertion that 'constructor inheritance is much much better'.  It very rarely is anyway, but here it is especially bad as your implementation is not in the prototype chain, which makes it significantly less efficient and consumes more memory.  Remember EventTarget is the base interface of every single DOM Node object. That was the reason for the down vote.

Comment: You assume that the prototype chain inheritance performance gains outweight their friction, which is debatable. Using classes over functions has some pros and cons. Furthermore Javascript is clearly not a language that you pick for performance. Of course when you gain something you always loose something too. When you think your approach is the best in every aspect, I have to say "Your approach is fundamentelly incorrect".

Comment: I believe that I'm 100% correct that the MDN approach is much worse then the contructor inheritance solution that I proposed even though it's less performant.

Comment: I don't assume it is more performant - I categorically know it is.  Aside that my custom implementation didn't use a class it used native prototype inheritance, either will be orders of magnitude more efficient than yours.  You offered poor, inaccurate advice, and I've called you on it.  You should have wondered _why_ MDN used prototypical inheritance in their example.  Feel free to test in Chrome Dev tools to satisfy yourself.

Comment: So in your opinion if more performance, it is the better soluton regardless of all other properties? This is defenitely not correct. I could give you examples, but we go out of scope.

Comment: You could have stated "your second solution has less performance" and not that it is "fundamentally wrong"

Comment: Btw why is it in your opinion both less less efficient and more memory consuming? I can be wrong but these two seem to contradict with eachother in javascript prototype chain theory (spec). Furthermore in my tests show absolute insignicant differences.

Comment: Maybe the ES6 way is more how it's expected to be done in JS, but both ways have it's merits in terms of memory and speed, there is no one best way.

Answer (score -2):

sample code snippet to use javascript EventTarget

`// attach event
var ev = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.call(null, 'alert', () => alert('ALERTED'))
// dispatch event
ev.dispatchEvent.call(null, new Event('alert'))`

Comment: how can you scope these events tho? are they all just global then?

Comment: @user633183, all callers, which specify `null`, will share one "object" (scope) `null`. And I think this **HACK** will stop working when browsers implement native private properties.