# How to inherit EventTarget Object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, events

I want to inherit EventTarget object.

So I tried the following code, which causes an error "Illegal constructor".

```
class OwnClass extends EventTarget {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
}
function eventHandler () {
  console.log( arguments );
}
let et = new OwnClass();
et.addEventListener( "Own Event", eventHandler );
et.dispatchEvent( new Event( "Own Event" ) );
```

So I use following code, currently.

```
class OwnClass extends Document {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
}
function eventHandler () {
  console.log( arguments );
}
let et = new OwnClass();
et.addEventListener( "Own Event", eventHandler );
et.dispatchEvent( new Event( "Own Event" ) );
```

But this cause meaningless memory usage.

Is there a way to inherit EventTarget directly?

Comment: Your code examples don't seem right: Both of them throw a `SyntaxError`, because you're calling `super()` in the class body rather than in the constructor or another function.

Comment: I miss wrapping with the constructor.

Comment: That's pretty much useless. If you just omit the constructor, it will automatically fall back to the parent constructor. Anyway, maybe you could [implement your own EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget#Example)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I had seen that already.
Is there no way to implement EventTarget without that MDN way?

Comment: No. [Full answer in this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22732701/1809564).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal Invocation on addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697502/illegal-invocation-on-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it comes a bit late for answering but now you can use the EventTarget class

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget

Comment: Thank you for your kind informing.