# Is there any EventEmitter in browser side that has similar logic in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, browser, eventemitter

It is so easy to use eventEmitter in node.js:

```
var e = new EventEmitter();
e.on('happy', function(){console.log('good')});
e.emit('happy');
```

Any client side EventEmitter in browser native?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @NaeemShaikh You are the man. Will you put in the answer? I will close this. Thanks, mate

Answer (score 145):

In modern browsers, there is EventTarget.

```
class MyClass extends EventTarget {
  doSomething() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('something'));
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
instance.addEventListener('something', (e) => {
  console.log('Instance fired "something".', e);
});
instance.doSomething();
```

Additional Resources:

- MDN documentation:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget
- Maga Zandaqo has an excellent detailed guide on Medium:
  https://medium.com/@zandaqo/eventtarget-the-future-of-javascript-event-systems-205ae32f5e6b
- Polyfill for old Safari and other incapable browsers:
    https://github.com/ungap/event-target
  *2024 Update: Polyfill no longer needed in most cases.*

Also, it's worth noting that Node.js supports EventTarget as of v15, so you can write the same code for both the server and the browser environments.

Answer (score 20):

While **there is no native API** akin to NodeJS' `EventEmitter`, there is a NPM package named "events" which makes you able to make event emitters in a browser environment.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')
 
const e = new EventEmitter()
e.on('message', function (text) {
  console.log(text)
})
e.emit('message', 'hello world')
```

in your case, it's

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')

const e = new EventEmitter();
e.on('happy', function() {
    console.log('good');
});
e.emit('happy');
```

Comment: OP is looking for a working on a native implementation on a browser not requiring a npm package.

Comment: @Ivan SO answers aren't just for the OP.   This is the answer I was looking for, and looking at the votes, other people too. I want the same code to work in both environments.

Comment: @Inigo In that case, you should have looked up or asked a different question which targets your requirement specifically. This answer, although correct, is just noise because it doesn't address what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @vighnesh153 I would argue that inundating SO with questions that differ in ***very tiny ways*** adds noise. Better to collect a variety of solutions to the crux of a problem under one question. Not to mention that the wording of the question, what people see in search results, "Is there any EventEmitter" instead of "Is there something like node's EventEmitter in browsers", if anything makes this the more valid answer. Not sure why you're nit-picking.

Comment: I'll remove this answer if it's redundant or unnecessary.
So, I'll assess it by checking if this comment receives 3 upvotes.

Answer (score 13):

This is enough for given case.

```
class EventEmitter{
    constructor(){
        this.callbacks = {}
    }

    on(event, cb){
        if(!this.callbacks[event]) this.callbacks[event] = [];
        this.callbacks[event].push(cb)
    }

    emit(event, data){
        let cbs = this.callbacks[event]
        if(cbs){
            cbs.forEach(cb => cb(data))
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
I just published little bit more evolved version of it. It is very simple yet probably enough:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/alpeventemitter

Comment: Typescript: `callbacks: { [s: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any)[] }`

Comment: This will result in out-of-order event handling when a event handler emits another event. You probably want to call the callbacks in emit after it returns, with setTimeout. Or put the events in a queue.

Answer (score 6):

Create a customized event in the client, and attach to dom element:

```
var event = new Event('my-event');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('my-event', function (e) { /* ... */ }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This is referred from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events
Thanks Naeem Shaikh

Comment: This only works on HTML elements, the question is how to make it work on an object like you can do in Node.

Comment: If you want to attach data within the dispatching event, you have to provide that in the `detail` property of the event object.
So you can receive it from the other end by accessing that property in the `event` object on the listener.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using this:

```js
export let createEventEmitter = () => {
   let callbackList: (() => any)[] = []

   return {
      on(callback: () => any) {
         callbackList.push(callback)
      },
      emit() {
         callbackList.forEach((callback) => {
            callback()
         })
      },
   }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to also add a cleanup functionality to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

2022 update: The BroadcatsChannel may provide a solution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

Comment: Only for web workers...

Comment: it works just fine in browser too.
in MDN it says : "The Broadcast Channel API allows basic communication between browsing contexts (that is, windows, tabs, frames, or iframes) and workers on the same origin."

Comment: While this is a great solution (especially for communicating between tabs and web/service workers), it also has more overhead than a simple event target, because it has the additional task of communicating between processes. If your goal is to create an event listener within a single page, Brad's answer is probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an npm package that do the same. You can use in Javascript or Typescript
[event-emitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tahasoft-event-emitter)

Example

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'tahasoft-event-emitter';

const onStatusChange = new EventEmitter();

function updateStatus() {
  // ...
  onStatusChange.emit();
}


// somewhere else, we want to add a listener when status change
onStatusChange.add(() => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A very basic solution

```js
function createEventEmitter() {
    const events = {}
    return {
        on: (name, listener) => {
            const listeners = events.hasOwnProperty(name)
                ? events[name]
                : (events[name] = [])
            listeners.push(listener)
        },
        emit: (name, ...params) => {
            const listeners = events[name] || []
            listeners.forEach((listener) => {
                listener(...params)
            })
        },
    }
}

const emitter = createEventEmitter()
emitter.on('myevent', (a, b) => {
    console.log(a, b)
})
emitter.emit('myevent', 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from Alparslan above. Here's one that uses the browser CustomEvent.

```
let EventEmitter = (function () {

    let elem = document.createElement("div")
 
    return {
        on: function (name, cb) {
            elem.addEventListener(name, (e) => cb(e.detail), false )
        },
        emit: function (name, data) {
            elem.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name, {detail: data}))
        } 
    }

})()
```

Answer (score -1):

[UPDATED to provide a fully working code]

Here is a complete code for implementing the EventEmitter class that can be used both in the browser and in node.

```js
/*
This file is part of web3.js.

web3.js is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

web3.js is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
along with web3.js.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
/* eslint-disable max-classes-per-file */

import { EventEmitter as EventEmitterAtNode } from 'events';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
type Callback = (params: any) => void | Promise<void>;

type EventTargetCallback = (params: CustomEvent) => void;

const wrapFunction =
    (fn: Callback): EventTargetCallback =>
    (params: CustomEvent) =>
        fn(params.detail);

/**
 * This class copy the behavior of Node.js EventEmitter class.
 * It is used to provide the same interface for the browser environment.
 */
class EventEmitterAtBrowser extends EventTarget {
    private _listeners: Record<string, [key: Callback, value: EventTargetCallback][]> = {};
    private maxListeners = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    public on(eventName: string, fn: Callback) {
        this.addEventListener(eventName, fn);
        return this;
    }

    public once(eventName: string, fn: Callback) {
        const onceCallback = async (params: Callback) => {
            this.off(eventName, onceCallback);
            await fn(params);
        };
        return this.on(eventName, onceCallback);
    }

    public off(eventName: string, fn: Callback) {
        this.removeEventListener(eventName, fn);
        return this;
    }

    public emit(eventName: string, params: unknown) {
        const event = new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail: params });
        return super.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    public listenerCount(eventName: string): number {
        const eventListeners = this._listeners[eventName];
        return eventListeners ? eventListeners.length : 0;
    }

    public listeners(eventName: string): Callback[] {
        return this._listeners[eventName].map(value => value[0]) || [];
    }

    public eventNames(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this._listeners);
    }

    public removeAllListeners() {
        Object.keys(this._listeners).forEach(event => {
            this._listeners[event].forEach(
                (listener: [key: Callback, value: EventTargetCallback]) => {
                    super.removeEventListener(event, listener[1] as EventListener);
                },
            );
        });

        this._listeners = {};
        return this;
    }

    public setMaxListeners(maxListeners: number) {
        this.maxListeners = maxListeners;
        return this;
    }

    public getMaxListeners(): number {
        return this.maxListeners;
    }

    public addEventListener(eventName: string, fn: Callback) {
        const wrappedFn = wrapFunction(fn);
        super.addEventListener(eventName, wrappedFn as EventListener);
        if (!this._listeners[eventName]) {
            this._listeners[eventName] = [];
        }
        this._listeners[eventName].push([fn, wrappedFn]);
    }

    public removeEventListener(eventName: string, fn: Callback) {
        const eventListeners = this._listeners[eventName];
        if (eventListeners) {
            const index = eventListeners.findIndex(item => item[0] === fn);
            if (index !== -1) {
                super.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListeners[index][1] as EventListener);
                eventListeners.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-mutable-exports
let EventEmitterType: typeof EventEmitterAtNode;
// Check if the code is running in a Node.js environment
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    EventEmitterType = EventEmitterAtNode;
} else {
    // Fallback for the browser environment
    EventEmitterType = EventEmitterAtBrowser as unknown as typeof EventEmitterAtNode;
}

export class EventEmitter extends EventEmitterType {}
```

Ref: https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/4.x/packages/web3-utils/src/event_emitter.ts

Answer (score -3):

You need a JavaScript library, like this https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter？

Comment: Not exactly, i want some the native one, instead of third part lib. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Node gained a native EventTarget in Node 15 (Oct 2020;) this question no longer applies

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#eventtarget-and-event-api

Comment: this question is about browser, not server side