# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "events". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: node.js

I want make my own socket.io, but I can`t reolve this error. My programm based on
custom events in node.js. There is collector.js:

```js
import EventEmitter from 'events'
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
export default eventEmitter 

eventEmitter.on('hi', () => {
    console.log('hi, Leahim')
})
```

this is index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="./collector.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
<script type="module">
    import eventEmitter from './collector.js'
</script>

</html>
```

The problem is included in tis error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "events". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".?
```

How can I fix that?
Thank you for listening to me.

Comment: You can't load node.js module in a browser

Comment: so, what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any EventEmitter in browser side that has similar logic in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831911/is-there-any-eventemitter-in-browser-side-that-has-similar-logic-in-nodejs)

Comment: oh... It doesn`t. I want emit events in a server too

Comment: so, I need to listen and emit in client and server part

Comment: You can't share code between server and client. These are separate applications and can't communicate through shared memory.

Comment: can I do what I want with http module?