# Call setState outside of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The following works as of React v18, but is it guaranteed to work correctly by React semantics?

The "rules of hooks" only talk about calling the hook itself in the component, there's no mention of whether or not it's okay to call the dispatcher returned from the `useState` hook outside of React

Note that the dispatcher here is setting the state itself, it is not taking a lazily evaluated function, in case that matters.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-mountain-8g7vx5?file=/src/index.js)

```js
let dispatcher = null 

// Rendered via React
function MyComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set the global var to this components setState
    dispatcher = setState;
    return () => {
      // on unmount, reset the global var to null
      dispatcher = null;
    }
  }, [setState]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Count: {state}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Rendered outside of React
const elem = document.getElementById("button");
let clickCount = 1;
elem.onclick = () => {
  if(dispatcher) {
    // call the global var which is the React component's setState()
    dispatcher(++clickCount);
  }
};
```

Comment: why cannot directly use `setState`

Comment: Ideally, if you want to update something within React from outside React, you should be publishing an event and then subscribing to that event in the useEffect.

Comment: @vighnesh153 - isn't that identical to what's happening here? just rename `dispatcher` to `listener`.

Comment: Here, you are directly accessing the `setState` function outside of React. What I said was to create an PubSub-like model outside of React and then subscribe to it, inside of React. Kind of like `window.addEventListener`. You could create a global event emitter as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831911/is-there-any-eventemitter-in-browser-side-that-has-similar-logic-in-nodejs What you have done in the question definitely works, but is not considered idiomatic React code.Also, testability of this code will take a hit.

Comment: It's the same thing. I'm just doing it more concisely with having a single global var, but a global `EventEmitter` that holds listener callbacks would call those callbacks from outside React when the event fires (the subscribing from within react doesn't call it, `EventEmitter` does)

Comment: > What you have done in the question definitely works

But what I'm wondering is if that's just good luck, or if this is guaranteed to work... React hooks do lots of magical things, depending on their exact order etc. I'm concerned with doing something that works but is unidiomatic and undocumented

Comment: The way you're doing it *should* work but like everyone else it's not clear to me why you *would*.

Comment: @JaredSmith - to understand the inner mechanics of React and whether or not this would break things.

Comment: @davidkomer "to understand the inner mechanics of React" you can do that by reading the source "whether or not this would break things" that is a direct contradiction to your first statement: the two halves don't fit together. The problem isn't just whether it works *now*, right *this minute*: the React devs are only obligated to maintain the guarantees they've explicitly made through their public API and any code written instead against implicit implementation details could break unexpectedly at any time. *That's* why I'm so confused.

Comment: It's like saying "tell me if there's any problems with the design of this house I deliberately build on a foundation of sand". I mean, I *could* but they aren't really relevant compared to the fact that you *built your house on an unstable foundation*. It doesn't matter how well you *built* it, it's still gonna come crashing down around your ears.

Comment: @JaredSmith - thank you for continuing to add to the reputation of stackoverflow being an awful place for discussion. I *have* read through the React source, at least parts of it. It's a nightmare codebase and incredibly difficult to parse. Specifically, the relevant file which is https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js - and I am not asking about any random version of React, I am talking about the current version (18), which the devs do honor semver and wouldn't break things the way you're suggesting

Comment: @JaredSmith - your analogy is off too. I am asking about calling the dispatcher from outside of the component tree. I'm not asking about some random unstable situation. I'm asking about *undocumented but internal guarantees* of the React codebase. It has to do with javascript binding and whether the call-site matters. If you don't know the answer to these questions, that's fine, but saying "I don't know therefore let's change the question to something else I do know" is less than helpful. Specifically: I did not ask for advice on alternative approaches at all.

Comment: "thank you for continuing to add to the reputation of stackoverflow being an awful place for discussion" yes that is correct: Stack Overflow is specifically a Q&A site and not suitable for freeform or speculative discussion. "the devs do honor semver and wouldn't break things the way you're suggesting" semver only covers *changes to the public API*, if you use it in a way they don't support they can break you without even a patch bump "I'm asking about undocumented but internal guarantees of the React codebase" no such thing

Comment: "saying 'I don't know therefore let's change the question to something else I do know' is less than helpful" from my perspective I'm saying "you can't have the guarantees you say you want" and you're shooting the messenger because that isn't what you wanted to hear. If you don't care about guarantees and you're just curious *that's absolutely fine*, and could even make for a good question here, if that's what you want you could change the question to something like "my mental model of how this works is X, could I verify that by using Y in Z context?" And remove concerns about "breaking things"

Comment: I didn't say "freeform" OR "speculative". You're attacking your own take. Anyway - React has a _ton_ of internal rules that aren't explicitly documented in official user manuals. The core devs write entire blogs detailing these things, and the internal code is sufficiently hairy and convoluted enough that these blogs are the only reasonable way to know what's reliable for a given React version. One of the more famous examples being https://overreacted.io/ ... you don't seem to understand this, and that's okay, but asking me questions like "why" is not helpful - and it's speculative!

Answer (score 0):

As suggest by [vighnesh153's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77059703/call-setstate-outside-of-react#comment135847332_77059703), you should use a pub/sub system, and register inside the component to the event.

This example dispatches the native browser [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#adding_custom_data_%E2%80%93_customevent) with the current count on the `document`. The component listens to the event, and sets the state as needed:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEvent = e => setState(e.detail);
  
    document.addEventListener('setReactState', handleEvent);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('setReactState', handleEvent);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Count: {state}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Rendered outside of React
let clickCount = 1;
document
  .getElementById('inc')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('setReactState', { detail: ++clickCount })
    );
  });
  
ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<hr>

<button id="inc">Increment from outside</div>
```

The main problem with your code is that you can't really reset (clear) from the global state, because the reference can be copied.

In the example, I'm assigning the reference in `dispatcher` to `dispatcher2` after 1 second, and I clear dispatcher after 2. Wait for the "dispatcher cleared" message, and click the "Icrement from outside" button, and it would still work.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

let dispatcher = null;

const Demo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set the global var to this components setState
    dispatcher = setState;
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatcher = null;
      
      console.log('dispatcher cleared');
    }, 2000);
    
    return () => {
      // on unmount, reset the global var to null
      dispatcher = null;
    }
  }, [setState]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Count: {state}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Rendered outside of React

setTimeout(() => {
  const dispatcher2 = dispatcher;
  let clickCount = 1;
  document
    .getElementById('inc')
    .addEventListener('click', () => {
      dispatcher2(++clickCount);
    });
}, 1000);
  
ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<hr>

<button id="inc">Increment from outside</div>
```

Comment: I agree about the potential problems with the architectural design, but what I really want to know is if it's actually a technical problem to call a React component's state setter from outside of React. In your example, it's being called from `document` (or the internal event listener caller inside of document) - which _might_ be okay, or it might not, I still don't quite know 100% that it's fine.

Comment: It's find for a set state function to be called from outside, for example `setTimeout`, the returning response of an api call, window events (scroll), observers, etc...

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated: the click event listener can just be added directly in the effect callback (and removed in the cleanup function) — there’s no need for additional custom events and subscriptions.

Comment: The question is - "how do you call setState from outside of React". In this case this is a simple button, but what happens when outside code needs to change the state? The custom event here is used as a pubsub system, not as a way to connect events to a button.