# Custom Object events

Tags: javascript, events, custom-events

I'm trying to emit custom events from my custom object like so:

```
var CustomObject = function () {
    this.customEvent = new Event('afterInit')
    /* init code goes here*/
    this.dispatchEvent(this.customEvent)
}
```

But my object cannot dispatch (i.e. dispatchEvent is not a property of my object) and I cannot bind to it. What is the correct syntax for firing custom events from custom objects?

Comment: Events are part of the DOM spec, not objects. It sounds like you have an X-Y problem. Why can't you accomplish what you need using a callback or promise instead?

Comment: dispatchEvent doesn't magically exist on any JavaScript object. It is a method of the [EventTarget interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-eventtarget).

Comment: If you want your custom object to be able to listen to DOM events, either make it a subclass of HTMLElement, or implement the complete EventTarget interface on it (not just `dispatchEvent` mind you, that would be misleading).

Comment: I see. Thanks for quick responses. I was sure there was a way to do it with events and seemed cleaner than callbacks. Promises it is

Comment: I think Promises and AsyncIterables are nicer. But if you'd like to actually use DOM Events, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186467/how-to-use-javascript-eventtarget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently, [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget) got a constructor, so you can actually use it for your JS object – before it was just an interface used only by DOM elements:

```
class CustomObject extends EventTarget {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.customEvent = new CustomEvent("afterinit");
  }

  init() {
    this.dispatchEvent(this.customEvent)
  }
};

let myObject = new CustomObject();
myObject.addEventListener("afterinit", console.log);
myObject.init();
```

Unfortunately, the support of `EventTarget`'s constructor is not good enough – see the link above –, and it's a *Web API*, means supported only in a browser's environment.

Comment: it's very unlikely we'll see EventTarget outside the browser, but Web APIs can and do end up in Node.js sometimes, like [URL](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api) and probably `fetch` soon ;)

Answer (score -1):

Objects do not have events. You have to implement that functionality on your own, then you can create new objects that inherit that using the `class` syntax:

```
 const handlers = Symbol.for("handlers");

 class EventEmitter {
   constructor(...args) {
     super(...args);
     this[handlers] = new Map;
   }

   on(name, handler) {
     if(!this[handlers].has(name)) {
       this[handlers].set(name, [handler]);
     } else {
       this[handlers].get(name).push(handler);
     }
   }

   trigger(name, ...args) {
     for(const handler of this[handlers].get(name) || [])
        handler(...args);
   }
}
```

Which you can use as:

```
const obj = new EventEmitter();
obj.on("test", alert);
obj.trigger("test", "hello world!");
```

Or with inheritance:

```
class Custom extends EventEmitter { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: I'd be happier if you gave an example of implementing EventTarget instead of the Node.js-style EventEmitter that's already everywhere on SO.

Comment: @Touffy ... Voila ... [How to implement an event dispatching system for ES/JS object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894457/how-to-implement-an-event-dispatching-system-for-es-js-object-types/74140087#74140087)