# Dispatch event from custom objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-dispatching

Is it possible to create custom events in objects? Something like this

```
var myCustomClass = function (param) {
  this.param = param;
};

myCustomClass.prototype.start = function(){
//Do staff
//fire event started
let event = new Event("started", {isStarted: true});
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

And in mai.js create an instance of `myCustomClass`

```
myCustomClass = new myCustomClassr(param);

myCustomClass.addEventListener('started', function () {
console.log("started");
});

myCustomClass.start();
```

With this code I am getting an error telling me that `dispatchEvent` is not a function

Comment: Mr.doob has a [repository for this](https://github.com/mrdoob/eventdispatcher.js)

Comment: possible approaches/solutions are provided by e.g. ... [_"How to make a Javascript class or object an event dispatcher?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587926/how-to-make-a-javascript-class-or-object-an-event-dispatcher) ... or ... [_"Custom Object events"_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51386367/2627243) ... or ... [_"How to implement an event dispatching system for ES/JS object types?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894457/how-to-implement-an-event-dispatching-system-for-es-js-object-types/74140087#74140087)

Answer (score 0):

dispatchEvent is not available on all JavaScript objects. This is very doable, but you need to inherit from an Event Emitter, so your class has event functionality.

There are zillions of Event Emitter things in JS, and you can also write your own pretty easily.

https://netbasal.com/javascript-the-magic-behind-event-emitter-cce3abcbcef9