# How to implement an event dispatching system for ES/JS object types?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, events, mixins

I want to be able to dispatch custom events (with properties) from my own javascript objects. I will have many objects so I want them to inherit this events dispatching interface so I dont repeat EventDispatcher code I have assign it as object prototype. Do you think is good approach?

```js
//event dispatcher

(function() {
  var WR_EventDispatcher = function() {

    var self = this;

    self.events = {};

    self.addEventListener = function(name, handler) {
      if (self.events.hasOwnProperty(name))
        self.events[name].push(handler);
      else
        self.events[name] = [handler];
    };

    self.removeEventListener = function(name, handler) {
      if (!self.events.hasOwnProperty(name))
        return;

      var index = self.events[name].indexOf(handler);
      if (index != -1)
        self.events[name].splice(index, 1);
    };

    self.fireEvent = function(name, args) {
      if (!self.events.hasOwnProperty(name))
        return;

      if (!args || !args.length)
        args = [];

      var evs = self.events[name],
        l = evs.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        evs[i].apply(null, args);
      }
    };

  };

  window.WR_EventDispatcher = WR_EventDispatcher;
}(window));

//my custom object

(function(window) {
  "use strict"
  var WR_PlaylistManager = function(data) {

    var self = this;

    function test() {
      var k = 6;
      self.fireEvent('NEXT_READY', [{
        'a': 2,
        'b': 11
      }]);
    }
  }

  WR_PlaylistManager.prototype = new WR_EventDispatcher();

  window.WR_PlaylistManager = WR_PlaylistManager;

}(window));


var _WR_PlaylistManager = new WR_PlaylistManager();

_WR_PlaylistManager.addEventListener('NEXT_READY', function(data) {

})
```

Comment: From the so far provided sole answer / approach are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

The next provided implementation of an `EventTargetMixin` (or `Observable` mixin) is due to partially answer the OP's question of this current thread but also in order to [reply to the OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74089510/javascipt-custom-object-and-events?noredirect=1#comment130850695_74089510) of another, [almost equal question of the same OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74089510/javascipt-custom-object-and-events) two-and-a-half weeks later.

1. **Answering the current thread's question**

   > *"I will have many objects so I want them to inherit this events dispatching interface so I dont repeat EventDispatcher code I have assign it as object prototype. Do you think is good approach?"*

   The inheritance based approach is going to fail.

   What happens when the OP does `WR_PlaylistManager.prototype = new WR_EventDispatcher()` is, that from this very point every `WR_PlaylistManager` instance refers to (shares) the same sole `WR_EventDispatcher` instance.

   **But the OP wants every `WR_PlaylistManager` instance to be *capable of featuring and managing its very own set of event listeners*. Thus the OP has to ensure *the creation of both an own context and an own scope* of what the OP refers to as `WR_EventDispatcher`.**

   Nevertheless exactly this can be accomplished with what the OP already came up with. The `WR_EventDispatcher` **function** only has to be **applied** to every `WR_PlaylistManager` instance (or any other object type) via e.g. ...

   ```
   const wrPlaylistManager = new WR_PlaylistManager();
   WR_EventDispatcher.call(wrPlaylistManager);
   ```

   Also, what the OP refers to as ... *"events dispatching interface"* ... is not an interface but is already an implementation which satisfies an interface. Such an approach (its implementation and application / usage) in my opinion should be referred to as [***function based mixin***](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript+%5D+%22function+based+mixin%22).

   Thus the OP's `WR_EventDispatcher` implementation should be renamed to either `Observable` or `EventTarget` or `withEventTarget` or `EventTargetMixin`.
2. **Answering how to implement a mixin for observable types / targets**

   In addition, even though such an **implementation looks like a constructor function, it is not** and also is discouraged to be used as such. Instead, **it always has to be applied to *any object* like this** ... `EventTargetMixin.call(anyObject)` ... where `anyObject` afterwards features the methods of an [***event target***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) like [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) and [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), where the OP should do both renaming `fireEvent` in favor of the latter method's name and also make `dispatchEvent` capable of dispatching real event types in a fail-/spoof- safe way.

   In order to achieve the just mentioned requirements more easily / readable / maintainable the next provided `EventTarget` mixin implementation internally uses two other abstractions [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) where the latter ensures the `handleEvent` method.

```js
// `EventTargetMixin`-tests with observable-types.


const firstObservableType = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
};
EventTargetMixin.call(firstObservableType);

const secondObservableType = EventTargetMixin.call({
  baz: 'baz',
  biz: 'biz',
});

function logEvent(evt) {
  console.log({ evt });
}
const firstListener = firstObservableType
  .addEventListener('woosh', logEvent);

const secondListener = secondObservableType
  .addEventListener('booom', logEvent);


// dispatching tests.


// - dispatching via just a valid string value.

firstObservableType.dispatchEvent('woosh');   // yep.

secondObservableType.dispatchEvent('woosh');  // nope.
secondObservableType.dispatchEvent('booom');  // yep.


// - dispatching via an object featuring a valid `type`.

firstObservableType.dispatchEvent({           // yep.
  type: 'woosh',
});
firstObservableType.dispatchEvent({           // nope.
  type: 'booom',
});

secondObservableType.dispatchEvent({          // yep.
  type: 'booom',
});


// - dispatching via an object and trying
//   to spoof essential event data.

firstObservableType.dispatchEvent({
  id: '________',                   // - spoofing fails.
  type: 'woosh',                    //
  target: null,                     //
  payload: {},                      // - payload data passes.
});
secondObservableType.dispatchEvent({
  id: '########',                   // - spoofing fails.
  type: 'booom',                    //
  target: void 0,                   //
  data: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],      // - payload data passes.
  moreData: 'bizz boooz buzz',      //
});


// the above dispatching happes non blocking ...
// ... watch the precedence of all the beneath test's loggings.


console.log({
  firstObservableType,
  secondObservableType,
  firstListener,
  secondListener,
});


// listener tests.

console.log(
  '\nfirstListener.getType() ...',
  firstListener.getType()
);
console.log(
  'firstListener.getHandler() ...',
  firstListener.getHandler()
);

console.log(
  '\nsecondListener.getType() ...',
  secondListener.getType()
);
console.log(
  'secondListener.getHandler() ...',
  secondListener.getHandler()
);


// observable and listener tests.

// - `hasEventListener` tests.

console.log( // yep.
  "\nfirstObservableType.hasEventListener('woosh', logEvent) ?..",
  firstObservableType.hasEventListener('woosh', logEvent)
);
console.log( // yep.
  'firstObservableType.hasEventListener(firstListener) ?..',
  firstObservableType.hasEventListener(firstListener)
);

console.log( // nope.
  '\nsecondObservableType.hasEventListener(firstListener) ?..',
  secondObservableType.hasEventListener(firstListener)
);
console.log( // nope.
  "secondObservableType.hasEventListener('booom', (x => x)) ?..",
  secondObservableType.hasEventListener('booom', (x => x))
);
console.log( // nope.
  "secondObservableType.hasEventListener('foo', logEvent) ?..",
  secondObservableType.hasEventListener('foo', logEvent)
);
console.log( // yep.
  "secondObservableType.hasEventListener('booom', logEvent) ?..",
  secondObservableType.hasEventListener('booom', logEvent)
);

// - `removeEventListener` tests.

console.log( // nope.
  "\nfirstObservableType.removeEventListener(secondListener) ?..",
  firstObservableType.removeEventListener(secondListener)
);
console.log( // yep.
  "firstObservableType.removeEventListener(firstListener) ?..",
  firstObservableType.removeEventListener(firstListener)
);
console.log( // nope.
  "firstObservableType.hasEventListener('woosh', logEvent) ?..",
  firstObservableType.hasEventListener('woosh', logEvent)
);

console.log( // nope.
  "\nsecondObservableType.removeEventListener('foo', logEvent) ?..",
  secondObservableType.removeEventListener('foo', logEvent)
);
console.log( // yep.
  "secondObservableType.removeEventListener('booom', logEvent) ?..",
  secondObservableType.removeEventListener('booom', logEvent)
);
console.log( // nope.
  "secondObservableType.hasEventListener(secondListener) ?..",
  secondObservableType.hasEventListener(secondListener)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>

// import `EventTargetMixin` from module.
const EventTargetMixin = (function () {

  // implementation / module scope.

  function isString(value) {
    return (/^\[object\s+String\]$/)
      .test(
        Object.prototype.toString.call(value)
      );
  }
  function isFunction(value) {
    return (
      ('function' === typeof value) &&
      ('function' === typeof value.call) &&
      ('function' === typeof value.apply)
    );
  }

  // either `uuid` as of e.g. Robert Kieffer's
  // ... [https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid]
  // or ... Jed Schmidt's [https://gist.github.com/jed/982883]
  function uuid(value){
    return value
      ? (value^Math.random() * 16 >> value / 4).toString(16)
      : ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, uuid);
  }

  function sanitizeObject(value) {
    return (
      ('object' === typeof value) && value
    ) || {};
  }

  class Event {
    constructor({ id = uuid(), type, target, ...data }) {
      Object.assign(this, {
        id,
        type,
        target,
        ...data,
      });
    }
  }

  class EventListener {
    constructor(target, type, handler) {

      const initialEvent = new Event({ target, type });

      function handleEvent(evt) {
        // trying to be non blocking.
        setTimeout(handler, 0, new Event(

          // prevent spoofing of `initialEvent` data.
          Object.assign({}, sanitizeObject(evt), initialEvent)
        ));
      };
      function getHandler() {
        return handler;
      };
      function getType() {
        return type;
      };

      Object.assign(this, {
        handleEvent,
        getHandler,
        getType,
      });
    }
  }

  function EventTargetMixin() {
    const observable/*Target*/ = this;
    const listenersRegistry = new Map;

    function addEventListener(type, handler) {
      let reference;

      if (isString(type) && isFunction(handler)) {
        const listeners = listenersRegistry.get(type) ?? [];

        reference = listeners
          .find(listener => listener.getHandler() === handler);

        if (!reference) {
          reference = new EventListener(observable, type, handler);

          if (listeners.push(reference) === 1) {

            listenersRegistry.set(type, listeners);
          }          
        }
      }
      return reference;
    }

    function removeEventListener(type, handler) {
      let successfully = false;

      const listeners = listenersRegistry.get(type) ?? [];
      const idx = listeners
        .findIndex(listener => listener.getHandler() === handler);

      if (idx >= 0) {
        listeners.splice(idx, 1);

        successfully = true;
      }
      return successfully;
    }

    function dispatchEvent(evt) {
      const type = (
        (evt && ('object' === typeof evt) && isString(evt.type) && evt.type) ||
        (isString(evt) ? evt : null)
      );
      const listeners = listenersRegistry.get(type) ?? [];

      listeners
        .forEach(({ handleEvent }) => handleEvent(evt));

      // success state      
      return (listeners.length >= 1);
    }

    function hasEventListener(type, handler) {
      return !!(
        listenersRegistry.get(type) ?? []
      )
      .find(listener => listener.getHandler() === handler);
    }

    Object.defineProperties(observable, {
      addEventListener: {
        value: addEventListener,
      },
      removeEventListener: {
        value: function (typeOrListener, handler) {
          return (

            isString(typeOrListener) &&
            isFunction(handler) &&
            removeEventListener(typeOrListener, handler)

          ) || (

            (typeOrListener instanceof EventListener) &&
            removeEventListener(typeOrListener.getType(), typeOrListener.getHandler())

          ) || false;
        },
      },
      hasEventListener: {
        value: function (typeOrListener, handler) {
          return (

            isString(typeOrListener) &&
            isFunction(handler) &&
            hasEventListener(typeOrListener, handler)

          ) || (

            (typeOrListener instanceof EventListener) &&
            hasEventListener(typeOrListener.getType(), typeOrListener.getHandler())

          ) || false;
        },
      },
      dispatchEvent: {
        value: dispatchEvent,
      },
    });

    // return observable target/type.
    return observable;
  }

  // module's default export.
  return EventTargetMixin;

}());

</script>
```